# convert list with duplicate id to Map

Tags: apex, map, list, invocable-method

I am working on an apex which is used to clear Hierarchy field values on User records when a user is deactivated.
I am stuck at the last part of code. I have a List with same UserID but with different fields that needs to be updated

EX:

List lstUser

[0] Id= '123456789', Senior_Director__c = ''

[1] Id= '123456789', Director__c = ''

Create a new map Map<Id, User> newUserMap

I tried with newUserMap.putall(lstUser). It is taking the [1] and updating only Director__c but not Senior_Director__c.
Can someone provide me a solution to achieve the above

Answer (score 0):

Maps store only one value per key, so if you don't take care, you'll displace the old value. That leads to something like this:

```
User u = allUsers.get(someUserId);
if(u == null) {
  allUsers.put(someUserId, u = new User());
}
u.Director__c = null;
```

You can't combine multiple objects in to a single object in the map, you have to start with a map to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to add 6 rows in metadata with each of them having SOQL query. I am looping metadata list and using Database.query(Query__c)// query field in custom metadata. 1st and 2nd row when queried are fetching same user records

Comment: @HarshithSrinivas Yes, you just need to combine the records manually into one.